# Sharing a response object within a module, without passing as param

Tags: node.js, express, module, callback

If I assigned the `res` (result) object to a `module` level property, will it be unique for each request, or could a secondary request that is started before the callback finishes overwrite it?

```
var moduleData = {};

    router.route('/publishers/:id')
        .get(function(req, res) {

            var id = req.params.id;

            // Assigning the res property to a module level property called `moduleData`
            moduleData.res = res;

            db.findById('publishers', id, function(error, publishers) {

                someFurtherWork(publishers); // would rather not pass the res object around
            });

        });

function someFurtherWork(publishers) {

    someWork(publishers, function(error, data) {

         // NOW we send the data back to user... is `res` guranteed to be the same one that initiated the request?
         moduleData.res.send(data);
    });
}
```

The router is itself event driven, meaning that each `.get()` request is handled as a callback to the server, when the thread is available. This guarantees each response object is unique to the function. Will a module level property be overwritten by a second GET request here?

If so, what workarounds are there, because I **don't want to pass around my response object to multiple chained callback functions**, that don't use them until all the data is collected.

There's a good reason I'm doing this, because if I have a bunch of callbacks, and once they're all done, then I need my response object. I figured if I used the response as a module level property, it won't need to be passed around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unique scope of each request your app receives is the same as the scope of the first callback you provide to the router, any variable that is defined in the outer scope is global to all requests.

You have to move the declaration of your `var ModuleData = {}` to the top of the callback. And because you defined `someFurtherWork(publishers)` function inside the same callback then it will have access via the closure to `ModuleData` object and you can just use it.

And if what you only need is to have the `res` object available to your nested callback and function so you can just use it as long as they all have a common root scope which is the initial callback function. Aren't closures awesome!

Comment: I tried assuming the `res` object will be available up the callback closure chain, but in this case it is not. Pretty sure most callbacks have an isolated scope outside the initial callstack! All I get is an undefined variable in my callback chain. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: If you define your callback outside the initial callback then its closure does not include it thus it is undefined, in this case your only choice is to inject it as a callback parameter.

Comment: I guess so, that's the way to go. My only issue really is that it's not particularly elegant. Imagine you have a callback/function call chain that's 5 levels deep, you must pass the `res` to most of these, even though all they do is pass it along to the last one.

Comment: The real issue is calling separate functions from the callback. That's when the `arguments` of the parent function is lost...

Comment: you only need to pass it as a parameter to any function that is defined outside the initial callback, any other function that is defined inside has access to this object as long as the parent function has access to it. That is just how javascript scopes are.

Comment: I know that, the issue is calling a function inside a callback loses the parent's scope. Thanks anyway.